# CUDA: Is there any api for element wise vector product in cublas?

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am trying to implement the element wise (Hadamard) product of vector such as the `.*` operation in Matlab. For example, if you type the following code in matlab:

```
[1,2,3].*[4,5,6]
```

It will answer:

```
[4,10,18]
```

I look up in the document of cublas library but can only find the function 2.4.6. `cublas<t>dot()`. It will return the dot product. However, what I need is the vector.

Comment: The one word answer is no.

Comment: Writing a kernel for this takes about a minute of your time and 15 lines of code. You don't need libraries for everything.